# In Matlab, I need a function/script that reads the element ij in two different images and outputs a new image which is the output of a function

Tags: function, matlab, image-processing

Pretty simple:

I need a script that reads the element ij of TWO images (same size). These two elements will be the input of a function that I have (actually a fuzzy logic system). I want the output of this function to form a new image, this one is made with the output of my function for **every** ij element of the TWO images opened before.

Thanks very much!

Rodrigo

Comment: Where's your attempt at solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The naive approach:

```
sz = size(img1);
out = zeros(sz,class(img1));
for i=1:sz(1)
     for j=1:sz(2)
         out(i,j) = myFunc(img1(i,j), img2(i,j));
     end
end
```

If your function is properly vectorized, you can just do:

```
out = myFunc(img1,img2);
```